# Passing Signatures Through AJAX for Security

Tags: php, ajax, session, jquery, session-variables

Last night I read about passing signatures through AJAX to improve security measure. Although I can't remember exactly what it prevents, I don't see any problem in implementing a measure like this. How would something like this look if I was implementing a signature into my AJAX code?

```
//variable below passes through AJAX
$signature = time();

//AJAX file receives variable, checks it against this variable below
$signature2 = time();

//if signature1 and signature 2 are more than one minute apart the ajax file is 
dead
```

Comment: That's the problem I don't know. I might close this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try passing a "key" generated randomly (one per user) and saved in a cookie. Then, you get the cookie from your JS get the value of the cookie and it will be sent it to the PHP file. This last one check if the key sent by ajax is the same that is in the cookie.

Comment: That's silly. Both the server AND the client can access BOTH cookies and AJAX variables. You're validating nothing.

Comment: I don't plan on using cookies and will stick with session data.